# dispalying S on 7 segments

Tags: verilog

This code should dispaly `S` for 1 sec then turn off for 1 sec and then dispaly `G` for 1 sec and then turn of for 1 sec and then display `S` for 1 sec and so on.

The problem is I am getting `S` then off then `G` then off then `G` then off and so on. I believe the error in the `hex7segm` module but I could not find a solution. Any help would be appreciated

Here is the code:

```
module asqw (output wire [6:0]a2g,output wire [3:0]AN,input wire fastclk);  
    wire slowclk;
    slow_clock xx(fastclk,slowclk);
    hex7segm zz(slowclk,a2g,AN);
endmodule

moduleslow_clock (input wire fastclk,output wire slowclk);

reg[27:0]period_count=0;

always@(posedge fastclk)

    begin

        period_count<=period_count+1;
    end

    assign slowclk=period_count[27];

endmodule

module hex7segm (input wire slowclk,

output reg [6:0]a2g,
output reg [3:0]AN
); 
reg[1:0]x;
reg[1:0]y=0;

always@(*)
    begin
        if(slowclk)
            begin
                x=y;
                AN= 4'b1110;
                y=y+1;
                if(y==2)  y=0;

                else


                    x=2;
                    AN= 4'b1110;

                    end
                        case(x)
                            0: a2g=7'b0100100;
                            1: a2g=7'b0100000;
                            2: a2g=7'b1111111;

                            default: a2g=7'b0100100;
                        endcase
                        end

                    endmodule
```

Comment: Your `always @(*)` results in latches as it is not combinational logic. FPGA synthesis tools usually dont like latches, so you should ensure you are using only combinational logic and FFs.

Comment: how do I correct it ?

Comment: Firstly, you need to split the combinational logic in your design from the sequential logic. In your current design, everything can be determined by the `slowclk` and `y`. Thus, you need to ensure both have registers; `slowclk` does as it in simply `period_count[27]` but `y` does not. So you'll need a `always @(posedge slowclk)` to control `y`. After that, everything else (`AN` and `a2g`) can be determined from the current value of `y` and `slowclk`. Note that whenever you use `always @(*)`, you need to be sure the variables assigned within the block as assigned to something for any input.

Comment: sorry but I still can't do it. I added an extra module for the combinational logic but the part about y I couldn't do it )":

Comment: is there an easier way to do it. Because I'm not an expert and it's a project must be handed in very soon ):

Comment: You need to break apart the `always @(*)`; it is both being your combinational logic and results in latches on `y`, `x` and `AN`. You can see this by asking 'what are the values of these variables is `slowclk` is 1'b0?' (Note, theyre assignments are currently wrapped in an if statement, so they hold value, thus latch). So, we need to separate these variables out. Realize first that `x` is just a function of `y` and `AN` is a constant. So, both of these can be set via assign statements. Now you just need to sort out `y`, which will just be a switch between displaying S or G. Good luck!

Comment: sorry for bothering you but is that what I should do                                                                           
  
 always@(posedge slowclk)
  begin
   if(slowclk)
    begin
     assign x=y;
     AN= 4'b1110;
     assign y=y+1;
     if(y==2) assign  y=0;
      
     else
        
      x=2;

Comment: after doing that I cant see the value of x=2 in the simulation !!

Comment: No, never use `assign` in an `always` block. Its a pointless construct and they shouldnt allow it. If you have this block `always @(*) if (slowclk) x = y;`, it is NOT combinational. What is `x` if not `slowclk`? The inputs are `slowclk` and `y` but the case where `slowclk` is 1'b0 is undefined. Thats the issue with your current code. That doesnt mean you just change it to `always @(posedge slowclk)` and hope it all works itself out. Understand you are describing hardware where `always @(*)` lets you describe combinational logic and `always @(posedge clk)` lets you describe a register.

Comment: It worked perfectly. thank you so so so much.I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi probably a little bit late to answer but here it is: The main problem is that you are mixing combinational and sequential logic. You need to separate these two. Moreover, I couldn't see why your new clock has a duty cycle of 50%.

Top module:

```
module asqw (
output [6:0]a2g,
input wire fastclk);

wire slowclk;
slow_clock xx(fastclk,slowclk);
hex7segm  zz(slowclk,a2g);

endmodule
```

Seven Segment Driver:

```
module hex7segm (
input wire slowclk,
output reg [6:0]a2g
); 
localparam S    =   7'b0100100;
localparam G    =   7'b0100000;
localparam OFF =    7'b1111111;

reg [2:0] state = 0;

always @ (posedge slowclk)
begin
    state <= (state == 5) ? 0 : state + 3'b1;
end

always @ (*)
begin
    case(state)
        0: a2g <= S;
        2: a2g <= G;
        4: a2g <= S;
        default: a2g <= OFF;
    endcase
end
endmodule
```

Slow clock:

```
module slow_clock (
input wire fastclk,
output reg slowclk = 0
);
reg[27:0]period_count = 0;

always@(posedge fastclk)
begin
    period_count <= (period_count == 25000000) ? 0 : period_count+ 28'b1;
    slowclk <= (period_count == 25000000) ? ~slowclk : slowclk;
end
endmodule
```